# PDOStatement::rowCount result when used after PDO::commit?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo

In the MySQL docs, there is a note about using `mysql_affected_rows` after a transaction commit:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

> **Note: Transactions**
>   If you are using transactions, you need to call **mysql_affected_rows()** after your INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE query, not after the COMMIT.

However, there is no such note on the `PDOStatement::rowCount` doc:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Does this mean the commit will not affect the affected rows count after INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE queries when using the `PDO` object?

Comment: after a commit, the meaning of `affected_rows` becomes unclear. Is it the total number of rows affected by the ENTIRE transaction? Or is it just the number of rows done the last operation within the transaction? If there were nested transactions that were rolled back, should any rows affected/undone also be counted, etc...

Comment: @MarcB The thing is, its a `PDOStatement->rowCount()` i.e. NOT `PDO->rowCount()` therefore it SHOULD row-count the last query not the last transaction.

Comment: mysql_affected_rows() is another way of doing PDOStatement->rowCount().
Both can only be called after a MySQL was done, because otherwise no rows would be affected.

Comment: Thanks for that @daemonfire300, but I believe you may have missed the point about the question, which is what specifically is the correct way of calling a PDO->rowCount() when using transactions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A PDOStatement is returned for each query that is executed. You will be able to use PDOStatement->rowCount() at any time in your code (during or after a transaction and rollback/commit doesn't matter). Each object takes care of maintaining itself.

The reason mysql_affected_rows has that transaction note is because it is only aware of a single mysql connection resource. This means that when you complete the transaction (commit/rollback) a new query has been sent to the DB, thus altering which result is being processed for the number of affected rows.