# Count of affected records in PDO transaction

Tags: php, sql, pdo, db2

I have a script that runs a pretty basic PDO transaction and it doe work (selects records and performs the merge based on those results)

So it successfully inserts/updates but I'm trying to get a count of accurate records and it doesn't work, it just returns 1 in powershell.

Starting with an empty database table and running this script, It inserts 1300 records successfully but `$count` prints '1'.
I'm simply trying to get record counts, success messages and errors for the purpose of an email when the script runs. Am I missing something?

```
while($arr = odbc_fetch_array($result)){

    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("
        MERGE INTO ORDER_STATUS as S
            USING (VALUES(
                        CAST(:ORDER_ID as INT),
                        CAST(:ORDER_STATUS as VARCHAR(45)),
                        CAST(:is_active as DECIMAL(1,0)),
                        CAST(:DATE_UPDATED as DATE)
                        )
                    )
            AS O(order_id, order_status, is_active, date_updated)    
            ON O.order_id = S.order_id  
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET order_status = O.order_status, is_active = O.is_active, date_updated = O.date_updated
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(order_id,order_status,is_active,date_updated) VALUES(O.order_id, O.order_status, O.is_active, O.date_updated)
    ");

    $PDO->beginTransaction();
    $i = 0;
    while($db2row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {

        if(++$i % 1000 == 0) {
            $PDO->commit();
            $PDO->beginTransaction();
        }
        $stmt->execute($db2row);
    }
    $PDO->commit();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    print_r($count);
}
```

Comment: I'm almost positive that that value of `1` you are seeing is correct. Take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272134/pdostatementrowcount-result-when-used-after-pdocommit) for more information.

Comment: This is on DB2, not MySQL, but I think I see the point there. So it's just returning the single last affected row? I'm basically trying to get it to report the count of all affected rows. So that initial insert should print 1300 for the count

Comment: With PDO I don't think that the underlying engine matters.

Comment: Row by row processing is very inefficient. Consider populating a session table with all the required rows (either in a fetch loop if the source-data comes from a different database than Db2, or if same database then use insert-into-select-from).  Finally once the session table is populated, use a single Merge statement to do the upsert in a single action, or in a batched-action dependent on volumetrics.

Comment: Ok so @Dave, the way the code is it prints 1, if I move the $count and print_r statement up within the while loop it prints 1, but 1300 times. Is there not just a way I can aggregate that within the loop so that it counts the row prints?

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the `$i` variable that you are already using to count the number of iterations? Or simply initialize another variable and add the results of rowCount to it each time through (though you already know that's going to be one). If you are concerned about it failing and the count not being accurate you'll want to wrap the `execute` in a try/catch block.

Comment: I may go the try/catch block just so I can cover all my bases. Thanks!